# VBA Userform, How do I Successfully Change Textbox Number Format Value

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, format, userform

I have a UF calculator I'm using to provide a length measurement. I have one textbox returning the result in decimal inches, but I also have a secondary that I would like to create an "easy read" for use with a standard US measuring tape.

The number format works well in a worksheet cell, but not in this textbox. Is there a better way to go about this?

My value is *106.59375*; as a worksheet function/format, the result is *106 19/32*. With VBA, I'm given *1/07*. I've played around with it, and it seems to be rounding value to *107*, then applying the format.

```
UFChordCalc.TBResult.Value = Round(chordLength, 3)
With UFChordCalc.TBER
    .Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.MRound(TBResult, 1 / 32)
    .Value = Format(.Value, "# ##/##")
End With
```

Comment: Do you have a dot in the number - this is a decimal point ? Try 10659375

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the value in 2 string variables - first -before the decimal mark, second - after decimal mark  in format "1/32"  and then stick together with "&"